# Installing go debuggers on OSX

Tags: installation, debugging, go

After installing go, I got the following lines:

> On OS X the debuggers must be installed setgrp procmod.
>   Read and run ./sudo.bash to install the debuggers.

Sorry for the beginner question, but what exactly does this mean?  What do I have to do to install the debuggers?

I ran ./sudo.bash but nothing happened.  Am I reading this too literally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you simply do as you did, and it copies the binaries from the build area to `/usr/local/bin` and then makes them belong to group `procmod` and SetGID.

Consider running:

```
sh -x sudo.bash
```

That should show you what it is doing as it does it.

I don't entirely agree with what that script does; I want the Go debuggers not in `/usr/local/bin`, thank you, but under $GOROOT, so I don't use the official `sudo.bash` but instead created my own `sudo.bash.goroot` which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
# license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

set -e
. ./env.bash

case "`uname`" in
Darwin)
    ;;
*)
    exit 0
esac

for i in prof cov
do
    sudo cp "$GOROOT"/src/cmd/$i/6$i $GOROOT/bin/6$i
    sudo chgrp procmod $GOROOT/bin/6$i
    sudo chmod g+s $GOROOT/bin/6$i
done
```

That works fine for me.